# STS IDE underline domain fields

Tags: grails, dns, ide, compiler-errors, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have the following situation:

I have a domain and I had to remove a field from it, but this field is referenced in several different locations and `grails` does not capture this error during compilation.

The STS IDE does underscores these fields, but it would be totally impractical to sweep the entire application looking for these flagged errors.

Is there another way I can catch these errors?

Comment: If you are using Grails > 2.x, then you can do a Static Type checking by using `@TypeChecked` at class level (property of Groovy 2.x) to catch compile time errors. Refer [this](http://www.infoq.com/articles/new-groovy-20) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

1. Good test coverage is going to be your best way of making sure you've captured everything when you make changes like this.
2. Make sure you're utilizing your IDE's refactoring functionality.  It won't always catch everything, but will help.  Also, read #1.
3. Do a search in STS for this field and clean up.  This is better than manual.  Also, read #1.
4. Read #1